# Login with google doesn't work when apk is signed with upload key

Tags: android, google-signin

Previously I could test Sign-in with Google after signing the apk and installing it to my device.

Now, I opted in the new App signing method of Google and now I cannot test sign-in with Google button in my app after signing it with the upload key. After clicking the sign-in with google button and choosing the profile, nothing happens.

If I upload the apk and it gets signed by the App signing key by Google, the sign-in with google just works.

I am changing the code and I want to test that it works before I upload to the store. Is there any way to test this without uploading while only signing with the upload key? Or any other way of doing it?

Comment: Related: [How can i test in-app payments when Google Play App Signing feature is enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45993630/295004)

Comment: Not a perfect answer but how about making a new flavour that builds/signs your app with your original signing key for direct deployment purposes?